# PasswordBox validation on text change instead of Lose Focus

Tags: silverlight, validation, binding, focus, keydown

**Framework**: Silverlight 4

I have a simple `ChildWindow` with Username `TextBox` and Password `PasswordBox`. I have attached an event handler to the window's `KeyDown` event.

```
private void onKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        cancelButtonClick(null, null);

    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        okButtonClick(null, null);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user presses Enter key on the keyboard, the program will behave as if the user had clicked the OK button.

**The problem** is the validation.

The default behavior for Silverlight's PasswordBox is to perform validation when the control loses focus. My `PasswordBox` is bound to some `User` object. When I click the Enter button, the event handler gets called, which in turn calls the `okButtonClick(null, null)`. The problem is that the `PasswordBox` has not yet lost the focus at that time, so the `user.Password` property, which the `PasswordBox` is bound to, is still empty.

I've tried to place `btnOK.Focus()` before the `okButtonClick(null, null)` but to no avail.

How to set the binding so that the control will update binding on every text change instead of on the `LostFocus` event? What is the right way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Did you think about create a DependencyProperty binded in TwoWay Mode with your PasswordBox? So when you fire the event "onKeyDown" you can use some kind of validation inside the method.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. The PasswordBox's Password property is already bound to my user object (obviously in TwoWay mode), but the value does not get assigned unless the PasswordBox loses focus. I could set the values manually in my onKeyDown handler, but that would make the binding in this case useless, because making such changes automatic is the motivation to use binding in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Use `PasswordChanged` event for `Passwordbox`.
`Textbox` has `TextboxChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by stumbling [upon this solution](http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2009/07/17/here-it-is-the-updatesourcetrigger-for-propertychanged-in-silverlight/).

It basicly uses attached property to subscribe to the TextChanged/PasswordChnaged events, and then in the event it updates the binding source. After adapting [the solution](http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2009/07/17/here-it-is-the-updatesourcetrigger-for-propertychanged-in-silverlight/) to my needs, here is what I got (and it works flawlessly):

```
public class BindingHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RefreshOnChangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RefreshOnChange", typeof(bool), typeof(BindingHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnRefreshOnChangeChanged));

    public static void SetRefreshOnChange(DependencyObject o, bool value)
    {
        o.SetValue(RefreshOnChangeProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetRefreshOnChange(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return (bool)o.GetValue(RefreshOnChangeProperty);
    }

    private static void OnRefreshOnChangeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((obj as TextBox) != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                (obj as TextBox).TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
            else
                (obj as TextBox).TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
        }

        if ((obj as PasswordBox) != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                (obj as PasswordBox).PasswordChanged += passwordBox_PasswordChanged;
            else
                (obj as PasswordBox).PasswordChanged -= passwordBox_PasswordChanged;
        }
    }

    static void passwordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        if (passwordBox != null)
        {
            BindingExpression binding = passwordBox.GetBindingExpression(PasswordBox.PasswordProperty);
            if (binding != null)
                binding.UpdateSource();
        }
    }

    static void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            BindingExpression binding = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            if (binding != null)
                binding.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```